# What do I do after extracting *.tar.gz file?

Tags: software-installation, tar

I downloaded and extracted `*.tar.gz` file. Here's the link - [Robomongo](https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0-rc7/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-rc7-linux-x86_64-2b7a8ca.tar.gz).
Then I located a folder named `Bin` and double clicked on a executable file. The program started to run. I didn't have to install it or anything. 
I have two questions:

What's this type of package called - Source code | Compiled | something else?

What's the typical place to put these extracted files on your computer?

Comment: You might be able to get a 'reopen' if you edit your question and ask more specifically about installing Robomongo rather than the more generic questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have downloaded a *compiled* version of [RoboMongo](https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0-rc7/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-rc7-linux-x86_64-2b7a8ca.tar.gz). Ordinarily such packages can be placed in either of 2 locations:

1. `$HOME/bin`
2. `/usr/local/bin`

I show the second option in this answer:

```
tar xvf robomongo-0.9.0-rc7-linux-x86_64-2b7a8ca.tar.gz
cd robomongo-0.9.0-rc7-linux-x86_64-2b7a8ca
sudo mv -v bin/* /usr/local/bin && sudo mv -v lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

If you then open the application with the command `robomongo` from the command line you will then have an option (for Xenial at least) on the sidebar to right click and 'Add to Dash' or 'Lock to Launcher':

[image]

It is not very tidy but this archive is not a fully developed *package* as such and lacks neat installation and removal options. However removal can be done *manually* with the following *two commands*:

```
sudo rm -v /usr/local/bin/{qt.conf,robomongo}
sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/lib/{imageformats,libQt5DBus.so,\
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.5.1,\
libicudata.so.54,libQt5DBus.so.5,libQt5Widgets.la,\
libicudata.so.54.1,libQt5DBus.so.5.5,libQt5Widgets.prl,\
libicui18n.so.54,libQt5DBus.so.5.5.1,libQt5Widgets.so,\
libicui18n.so.54.1,libQt5Gui.la,libQt5Widgets.so.5,\
libicuuc.so.54,libQt5Gui.prl,libQt5Widgets.so.5.5,\
libicuuc.so.54.1,libQt5Gui.so,libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1,\
libQt5Core.la,libQt5Gui.so.5,libQt5XcbQpa.la,\
libQt5Core.prl,libQt5Gui.so.5.5,libQt5XcbQpa.prl,\
libQt5Core.so,libQt5Gui.so.5.5.1,libQt5XcbQpa.so,\
libQt5Core.so.5,libQt5PrintSupport.la,libQt5XcbQpa.so.5,\
libQt5Core.so.5.5,libQt5PrintSupport.prl,libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5,\
libQt5Core.so.5.5.1,libQt5PrintSupport.so,libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.5.1,\
libQt5DBus.la,libQt5PrintSupport.so.5,platforms,\
libQt5DBus.prl,libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.5,platformthemes}
```

It takes a little bit of manual fiddling but this works nicely on my system and should on yours as well...

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov Great to see the issue is resolved for you! And have a great day :)